# Loop / map over array returned from .flatMap

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This is a really entry-level reactive programming question. The following code will log an array of `users` from github. How can I get access to loging each individual `user.login` using Rx?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Rx from 'rx'

let requestStream = Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users')

let getJSON = (url) => {
  return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
}

let responseStream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getJSON(requestUrl))
  })

responseStream.subscribe(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
})
```

I've tried:

```
let responseStream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getJSON(requestUrl))
  })
  .flatMap(user => {
    console.log(user)
  })
```

and:

```
let users = responseStream
  .flatMap(user => {
    console.log(user)
  })

users.subscribe(function(response) {
  // console.log(response)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get each individual user from the array, create and return a new observable of that array as follows:

```
let responseStream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return getJSON(requestUrl);
  })
  .flatMap(function(usersResponse) {
    return rx.Observable.from(usersResponse);
  })
  .doOnNext(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
  });
```

When you call `responseStream.subscribe(......)` it should now log each user out individually from the `.doOnNext()` method.

I used Mosho's answer as a base for this response with the assumption that the first flatMap returns an array of users from github.

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap` handler can return promises, so you don't need `fromPromise`.

To get what you need, an observable of the separate items, you can just use `flatMap` again, it does exactly what you want. You almost had it right the first try, but the projection (which is merged to a new, returned observable) is what's returned from the `flatMap` handler.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Rx from 'rx'

let requestStream = Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users')

let getJSON = (url) => {
  return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
}

let responseStream = requestStream
  .flatMap(function(requestUrl) {
    return getJSON(requestUrl);
  })
  .flatMap(function(x) {
      return x;
  });

responseStream.subscribe(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
})
```

This way, each element in the array is projected onto a new observable, and they are all merged into a single observable, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: The second `flatMap` is still returning the entire `users` object and not the individual `user`.